# How can I explode an animated PNG?

Tags: windows, png, image-editing

Websites like [GIF Explode](http://gif-explode.com/) allow you to "explode" an animated GIF into its component frames, and similar results are presumably easy to achieve with standard image-editing tools like GIMP, ImageMagick, etc. Alas, all the tools I've found thus far are limited to working with GIFs.

How can I explode an animated *PNG*? I'm willing to work with pretty much anything that will run in the browser or natively on Windows, including a programmatic interface to some sort of library if need be.

For an example of an animated PNG, check out [this example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animated_PNG_example_bouncing_beach_ball.png) (embedded below). Note that many modern browsers don't natively support APNGs, so you might not actually be able to see it animate.

[image: a beach ball that is apparently animated]

Comment: Good question. I learnt something today.

Comment: FWIW: Old Opera and Firefox support it; Newest Chrome, IE and Opera 15+ do not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [APNG Disassembler](http://apngdis.sourceforge.net/) (for Windows).  They have a GUI version and a command line version of the program.  I tried the GUI version and it's pretty simple: specify the APNG input file and a prefix for all the output files, and click a button.  It will output a PNG file (with the prefix you specified along with a number) representing each frame, along with a TXT file for each frame containing the delay for that frame.